# How do I make a ZoomControl on a MapView transparent?

Tags: android, controls, zooming, android-mapview, transparent

I have a bunch of buttons on my `MapView` already transparent so I would like to make the built in zoom control at the bottom transparent also.  The `getZoomControl()` on `MapView` is deprecated.  Anyone have an idea of how to get a hold of the `Buttons` in the control without the `getZoomControl`?

**Edit:**

So I figured it out.  It turns out that the `ZoomButtonsController` has a container that is just a `ViewGroup`.  I can parse through that containers children to find the object that is an instanceof a `ZoomControl`, which is a down the line instance of a `ViewGroup`.  I can parse through the children of the `ZoomControl` to get the `ZoomButtons` that it contains.  `getBackground()` of the `ZoomButton` and `setAlpha()`.

Here is my code:

```
android.widget.ZoomButtonsController zbc = mapView.getZoomButtonsController();
    ViewGroup container = zbc.getContainer();
    for (int i = 0; i < container.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = container.getChildAt(i);
        if (child instanceof ZoomControls) {
            ViewGroup zoomC = (ViewGroup)child;
            for (int j = 0; j < zoomC.getChildCount(); j++) {
                View btn = zoomC.getChildAt(j);
                if ( btn instanceof ZoomButton ) { 
                    ((ZoomButton)btn).getBackground().setAlpha(120);
                }
            }
            break;
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my understanding it is deprecated in `android.view.View` but it resides in `android.widget.ZoomButtonsController`. Not sure if that helps. Let me know.

[Here is some documentation.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ZoomButtonsController.html#getZoomControls%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

remove the built in zoom buttons and use your own buttons and set their actions to perform zoom actions. you can make the buttons look the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [setBuiltInZoomControls(boolean)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView#setBuiltInZoomControls%28boolean%29) as suggested in the doc.